# Удалить ячейку массива по его индексу, избавится от пустого места после удаления, сдвинуть заполненные ячейки на место пустых

Tags: java, массивы

Суть вопроса. Нам нужно удалить элемент из массива по его индексу, потом сдвинуть все элементы так, что бы между заполненными ячейками не было null элементов.
Пример:

Допустим мы имеем массив из шести ячеек, заполнено из которых лишь четыре в таком порядке :

```
овощ[0] огурчик;
овощ[1] романеску;
овощ[2] патисон;
овощ[3] null;
овощ[4] артишок;
овощ[5] null;
```

нам нужно удалить овощ[2], это просто:

```
овощ[0] огурчик;
овощ[1] романеску;
овощ[2] null;
овощ[3] null;
овощ[4] артишок;
овощ[5] null;
```

а дальше, нужно привести массив к виду:

```
овощ[0] огурчик;
овощ[1] романеску;
овощ[2] артишок;
овощ[3] null;
овощ[4] null;
овощ[5] null;
```

До чего я смог доехать:

```
public class Shop {
    public Product[] delete(Product[] products, int index) {
        for (int i = index; i < products.length - 1; i++) {
            if (products[i] != null) { 
                products[i] = products[i++]; 
                products[i] = null;
            }
        } return products;
    }
}
```

В этом коде я проверяю, не является ли null тот продукт который я хочу удалить, после удачной проверки присваиваю удаляемому продукту значение следующего по индексу, а дальше об**NULL**яю копируемый продукт.

Дальше мозг заедает, индексы плывут, помогите ради за*бита, во имя святого бубна!
Спасибо, внатуре...

Comment: Вам нужен именно массив? Для такой цели идеально подошли бы List/ArrayList

Comment: Нет, такое решение не подойдёт, тут именно, надо страдать через циклы... Но если у Вас есть решение через  List/ArrayList  тоже буду рад, посмотреть интересно, да и в будущем оно обязательно пригодится)

Comment: Что в List что в  ArrayList при удалении одного из содержащихся в них объектов через метод remove() все индексы объектов сами по себе сдвигаются к виду к которому у вас нужно приводить. Сейчас попробую придумать как реализовать это с обычным массивом.

Comment: Эййй... чего минусят то вопрос, я юный ещё, могу глупости писать, зачем обижать то(( Лучше б помогли разобраться(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например такой код справится с этим:

```
  static String[] delete(String[] array, int index) {

    array[index] = null;

    for (int x = 0; x<array.length-1;x++) {

      if (array[x]==null) {

         for (int y=x;y<array.length-1;y++) {

           if(array[y+1]!=null) {

             array[x] = array[y+1];
             array[y+1] = null;
             break;
           }
        }
      }
   }

   return array;

   }
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо! Но.... Тут моя вина,не написал в вопросе, но это видно в моём коде. Нам нужно не просто удалить ячейку массива, а удалить ее по индексу public Product[] delete(Product[] products, **int index**) Прошу прощения)

Comment: Добавил в код то что вам нужно.
Если ответ решает проблему не забудьте поставить у ответа галочку что это решение.

Comment: Один нюанс, в самом начале Вы обнуляете весь массив array[index] = null , то есть, допустим я хочу удалить array[index] (овощ[2]), то в цикл у меня пойдёт **null** что выдаст ошибку при компиляции (  Думаю правильным будет прямо в цикле **for** приравнять **int i = index**

Comment: Вы что-то не так делаете. Я проверял код перед тем как показать.
Что у вас виде аргумента index указывается?

Comment: Так метод изначально просит ввести String и int **delete(String[] array, int index)**

Comment: Покажите как вы вызываете метод и какие аргументы указываете при этом.

Comment: Всё!!! Прозрел!!! Прошу прощение за непонимание)!